# When trying to install OS in Hyper-V, it ignores boot order and goes to "Start PXE over IPv4" instantly

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to create a VM from an .iso file on my computer. In my boot order settings, the DVD Drive with as value the .iso is at the top. I've tried several different VM's (Ubuntu18.04, Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016) all of which give me the same problem where they don't boot from the .iso file. Pressing any key doesn't do anything.

I followed tutorials from both my lecturers and articles online when creating the VM's.

I am clueless as to what I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated

[Black "Start PXE over IPv4 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI4Pd.png)
[Error message when trying Windows 10 after the black "Start PXE over IPv4" screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kM2T.png)
[Error message when trying Ubuntu after the black "Start PXE over IPv4" screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA8Gp.png)

Comment: Have you create gen 1 or gen2 vm?

Comment: My teacher told me I should use gen2. That didn't work. I fixed the issue by using gen1.

Comment: Switching to gen 1 worked for me when trying to install Win Server 2019. The below solutions did not for whatever reason.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rmxMM_-2S0 . By Pressing Space and loading solved the problem. I kept the the video for your reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just go into VM Settings / Firmware and change the boot order by moving the VHDX image to the top.

Changing to Generation 2 VM is not necessary.

Comment: That cracked it, thanks

Answer (score 106):

Try disabling Secure boot in the "Security" section of the settings.

I had the same problem with a gen2 Linux vm (running in Hyper-V Manager 10.0.17763.1). Turning off "Enable Secure Boot" allowed booting from an .iso. 
I think in some other versions of Hyper-V Manager the setting is under "Firmware"

[image: VM Settings]

Comment: I couldn't figure out why my fresh HyperV wouldn't boot from my Debian ISO. Turning this off helped. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft has some pretty good details about what features are supported on various flavors of Linux and FreeBSD, and a note: 

Generation 2 virtual machines have secure boot enabled by default and some Linux virtual machines will not boot unless the secure boot option is disabled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v

Comment: This is it! Should be accepted. Help me a lot! ThANKS

Comment: This is a quick and dirty solution, if you are running a newer Linux distro that supports secure boot, take a look at some of the other answers that talk about using the "Microsoft UEFI certificate Authority" for secure boot.

Answer (score 30):

This occurred when I was trying to boot from a Win 10 ISO. After the "Press any key to Boot from DVD..." message displays, it jumps almost immediately to trying to boot from the network (PXE over IPv4). The solution for me was to select 'Reset' from the Hyper-V menu and then immediately start hitting a key before the message showed up.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to install Windows Server 2019 VM. This method solved it, but can anyone explain what happened and why it got resolved this way?

Comment: This is the one. Kind of a dumb issue, but thank you for saving my sanity.

Answer (score 12):

Worked for me:

1. Create a new VM.
2. A "New Virtual Machine Wizard" will start.
3. During step 3 - "Specify Generation", choose "Generation 1"

Comment: Very good answer which I upvoted, indeed it's working even for new os or especially when you convert .ovf virtual machines to .vhd or .vhdx
After aving exported a virtual machine from VMware for example.

Answer (score 11):

- **When using Windows10** - moving the VHDX to the top Boot order was the solution in my case.
- **When using Linux** - Changing secure boot to use "Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority" was the solution. I tested CentOS_Stream & Mint - same problem, same solution.

Comment: Changing secure boot to use "Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority" worked for me. I've installed Ubuntu Server, Generation 2 VM.

Comment: This answer (and MaxAlt's) should be the accepted one. Hyper-V gave 3 options for the secure boot template, and only choosing "Microsoft Windows" or "Microsoft UEFI Cert..." will Hyper-V say secure boot is enabled, and it seems only UEFI works for Linux (Works for Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 5):

I left enabled "Enable Secure Boot" flag, but selected a different template: from "Microsoft Windows" to "Microsoft UEFI certificate Authority" for my Centos 7 distribution hosted by Windows 10.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/Generation-2-virtual-machine-security-settings-for-Hyper-V) tells the UEFI is needed for Linux installation.

Comment: I used this approach to install RHEL 8 from a DVD ISO.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 20.04 too

Answer (score 4):

The only solution in my case was to re-create the VM in Generation 1. Changing the boor order or disabling Secure Boot did not resolved the issue at all.

It seems "Quick Create" creates VM in Generation 2 by default. You have to Go with "New" instead of "Quick Create" to choose Generation 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case I left disabled the "Enable Secure Boot" flag and it worked pretty

Answer (score 1):

I tried every answer here, so what I did that ended up working is:

Create with New instead of Quick Create

Select Generation 2

Disable Secure Boot

Move boot from hard disk to the top

On the black screen with the "Start PXE..." message, I selected "Action -> ctrl-alt-del" from the Hyper-V menu bar.

This reset the screen and gave me time to press a key to boot from DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a vhdx image from a Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V environment to Windows 10 Hyper-V, I had to create a Generation 1 VM.  Generation 2 did NOT work.  It booted without the PXE over IPV4 error then.

Answer (score 0):

For a Gen2 VM to instal Windows 10/11 you neeed the following simple steps:

Assuming you have your ISO mounted in the virtual dvd drive...

1. Right click your Gen2 VM in hyperV and select settings.
2. Click the security tab and check the box "Enable Secure Boot" and "Enable Trusted Platform Module" then save your settings.
3. Connect to the VM with it turned off. Press the power on button and then keep pressing your enter key as the Hyper-V boot screen appears until you boot into windows installer.

Now you are able to install Windows 11 on a Gen2 VM with secureboot and TPM enabled.